# Complete list of all different Intl.NumberFormats

Tags: javascript, concurrency, number-formatting

I'm looking for a complete list of all the different Intl.NumberFormats.

The [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) page shows 3 different formats.

```
ja-JP -> "￥123,457"
de-DE -> 123.456,79 €
en-IN -> 1,23,000
```

Is this all? Or is there more?

Comment: Which languages other than those listed at the linked document have you passed to the function as `locales`?

Comment: does [ES2015 documentation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/2.0/#sec-properties-of-intl-numberformat-prototype-object) help?

Comment: The format used is based on the language and options provided, so a "complete list" would be all combinations of language, numbering system and options. That would be a very large list. BTW, "ja-JP" is a language code, you've followed that with a value formatted as currency, which is not included in the format string.

Comment: @ChrisRiebschlager A link to a download is not necessary. The specifications relevant to the subject matter are available online.

Comment: @RobG The list as an XML document has a `Content-Length` of `5626`.

Comment: @guest271314—what list? The OP asks for "*a complete list of all the different Intl.NumberFormats*".

Comment: @RobG ISO 4217 currency codes. The language codes specification can be located by OP by following the link at the original question https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5646

Comment: @ChrisRiebschlager How is the linked GitHub repository related to the question?

Comment: @guest271314—that's not what I understand from the OP (which doesn't provide enough information to answer, which is why there are so many comments, so maybe you're right). The example "formats" don't include currency code, only language codes, but the expected results would also require a currency code at least. A list of  BCP 47 language tags is available at [*IANA.org*](http://www.langtag.net/registries.html) in various formats. I'm sure the OP can use a search engine too… ;-)

Answer (score -6, accepted):

All different formats available worldwide.

```
$c = '{
"en_EN": "$100,000.00",
"de_DE": "100.000,00 $",
"af_AF": "$ 100,000.00",
"am_AM": "US$100,000.00",
"ar_AR": "١٠٠٬٠٠٠٫٠٠ US$",
"bn_BN": "১,০০,০০০.০০US$",
"bg_BG": "100000,00 щ.д.",
"ca_CA": "100.000,00 USD",
"cs_CS": "100 000,00 US$",
"nl_NL": "US$ 100.000,00",
"et_ET": "100 000,00 $",
"fr_FR": "100 000,00 $US",
"he_HE": "‏100,000.00 $",
"hi_HI": "$1,00,000.00",
"it_IT": "100.000,00 US$",
"nb_NB": "USD 100 000,00",
"ms_MS": "USD100,000.00",
"id_ID": "US$100.000,00",
"pl_PL": "100 000,00 USD"}';
```

Comment: This answer is definitely wrong. I don't know how it became the accepted answer. If you try to use any of these codes, Intl.NumberFormat throws an error due to it being invalid. It's possible these codes are for iOS, but the question is asked for JavaScript.

Comment: When replacing `_` with `-` (eg. `en-EN`), it's case insensitive btw, it's working for almost all of the above listed language codes. Tried all of the listed codes. Only `af-AF`, and one other, is not showing the listed result.

Answer (score 6):

Intl was introduced here https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/12/introducing-the-javascript-internationalization-api/ with these takeaways:

1. There's no official list, since ["The api is best-effort"](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/12/introducing-the-javascript-internationalization-api/)
2. By default, browsers accepts ALL correctly formatted codes ([BCP 47 is mentioned](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/) and then [finds the *best fit*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#Locale_identification_and_negotiation)
3. You might specify *lookup only* to disable the *best fit* algorithm, and then you could get a list of all countries and language codes and that way run through all combinations *for a specific browser on a specific OS with a specific list of installed languages* but I guess that's not what you want to hear if you're building a web project. But you might want to make use of [supportedLocalesOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat/supportedLocalesOf) to have something *locally relevant* to choose from.
4. Under the hood browsers typically use [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) or similar

tl;dr: So if you send in your best guess at a valid locale, the best fit algorithm will get you something usable!

*Valid locale?*
According to the documentation and my earlier research, the `Intl` javascript API expects you to format your locale codes according to *BCP 47*.

Answer (score 1):

Go through this it has all the format available

Some of popular locales:

```
pl_PL      = 1 205,34 zł
en_US      = $1,205.34
en_GB      = £1,205.34
en_IE      = €1,205.34
de_DE      = 1.205,34 €
fr_FR      = 1 205,34 €
br_FR      = € 1 205,34
ja_JP      = ￥1,205
pt_TL      = 1 205,34 US$
fr_CA      = 1 205,34 $
en_CA      = $1,205.34
```

And for All possible locales visit:
https://gist.github.com/ncreated/9934896

Comment: Your link is about iOS locales. The question is tagged #javascript and the question also specifies they want to get locales for `Intl.NumberFormat`

Comment: These are IOS locales

Answer (score 1):

```
en-IE      = €1,205.34
ro-MD      = 1.205,34 MDL
br         = ¤ 1 205,34
en-GY      = $1,205
es-GT      = Q1,205.34
```

All Locale Visit : https://gist.github.com/raushankrjha/d1c7e35cf87e69aa8b4208a8171a8416