# Intl.NumberFormat does not support "en-FR"? How to control the decimal & group characters?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, locale, react-intl

I've noticed that `en-FR` does not appear to be a fully supported locale by the `Intl.NumberFormat` API.

I've not found any *official* list of supported locales by the [`Intl` api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl). However, I can assume [the list](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/formatjs/formatjs/main/packages/intl-numberformat/supported-locales.generated.ts) from a fairly popular polyfill by `formatjs`

That list of supported locales does not include `en-FR`. Maybe I'm being naive but I think this locale would be a commonly supported locale, for example for users who speak English but are in a French region.

```
const numberFormatter = Intl.NumberFormat('en-FR');

//numberFormatter.resolvedOptions()
{
    "locale": "en",
    "numberingSystem": "latn",
    "style": "decimal",
    "minimumIntegerDigits": 1,
    "minimumFractionDigits": 0,
    "maximumFractionDigits": 3,
    "useGrouping": "auto",
    "notation": "standard",
    "signDisplay": "auto",
    "roundingMode": "halfExpand",
    "roundingIncrement": 1,
    "trailingZeroDisplay": "auto",
    "roundingPriority": "auto"
}

//numberFormatter.formatToParts(1234.56)
1,234.56
```

When a new `Intl.NumberFormat` is contrusted with the `en-FR` locale, it appears to fallback to just a `en` locale. This is problematic as the `en` locale will produce a different number format than an `en-FR` locale would:

| Locale | Input | Expected Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `en-FR` | 12345.56 | 1 234,56 |
| `en` | 12345.56 | 1,2345.56 |

Is there any way to control the `decimal` or `group` characters of the `Intl.NumberFormat` API? Or is there any way to add a custom locale support?

The use case stems from the iOS ecosystem, where a user may have a language of locale `en-GB`, but a region setting of `en-FR`. The numbers, dates, currencies should reflect the "France" region, but the actual translations should reflect the "English (United Kingdom)" language.

Comment: There is no `en-FR` because there is no french dialect of english

Comment: do you mean `fr`? see [Complete list of all different Intl.NumberFormats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48273724/complete-list-of-all-different-intl-numberformats) for discussion about locale references. Also [LocalePlanet](https://www.localeplanet.com/icu/en/index.html)

Comment: @Konrad That’s correct, but supplying the “en-FR“ should utilize the region code (“FR”) with concern to how numbers, dates, and currency are formatted, no?